# Read value from local variable or from object in for-loops and if-statements?

Tags: c#, for-loop, conditional-statements

In a for-loop in C#, which of the following codeblocks are the best performance wise? Or is there no difference?
The diffenrence is whether the condition is saved in a local variable or read directly from an object.

Option 1

```
float maxDepth = 0;
int maxnumber = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < defects.Total; i++)
{
    if (defects[i].Depth > maxDepth)
    {
        maxDepth = defects[i].Depth;
        maxnumber = i;
    }
}
```

Option 2

```
float maxDepth = 0;
int maxnumber = 0

int defectNumber = defects.Total;
for (int i = 0; i < defectNumber; i++)
{
    if (defects[i].Depth > maxDepth)
    {
        maxDepth = defects[i].Depth;
        maxnumber = i;
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if this question have been asked a lot, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Anders

Comment: The compiler will know that Total doesn't change during the loop and will replace it with the value, so you will end up with the second code anyway.

Comment: @MBen: How could the compiler know that? *We* don't know that. We don't know what `defects.Total` does.

Comment: @JonSkeet Doesn't the compiler see that Total is not changed in our loop and replace it with the constant?

Comment: @MBen: Where's the declaration for `Total`? Perhaps it's implemented as `public int Total { get { DateTime.Now.Seconds; } }`

Comment: Total is a property, looks like in the documentation that it is implemented as public int Total { get; }.
It is from the EmguCV library.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand this correctly, if it is implemented as a get function the compiler can't see that this is a constant value and will have to check for every iteration, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all such questions you can use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` like this.

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

float maxDepth = 0; 
int maxnumber = 0;  
for (int i = 0; i < defects.Total; i++) 
{    
    if (defects[i].Depth > maxDepth)     
    {         
        maxDepth = defects[i].Depth;         
        maxnumber = i;     
    } 
} 

stopwatch.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("Elapesed time for method 1: {0} msec.", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
stopwatch.Reset();
stopwatch.Start();

maxDepth = 0; 
maxnumber = 0;  
int defectNumber = defects.Total; 
for (int i = 0; i < defectNumber; i++)     
{    
    if (defects[i].Depth > maxDepth)     
    {         
        maxDepth = defects[i].Depth;         
        maxnumber = i;     
    } 
} 
stopwatch.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("Elapesed time for method 2: {0} msec.", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Then you got exact information. (The best way is to take several runs and use the mean value)

Comment: Guess I'll try this. Just thought there was a generel answer to this:)

Comment: @AndersJørgensen: Of course there are general answers to everything. ;-) But that's theory, I always make the cross check to reality and do some measuring.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example has to keep resolving defects.Total on every pass through the loop.  In general, that would be slower than having a value in a native int.  I don't have knowledge of the internal workings of C#, so I can't say for sure which is faster or by how much, but overall I'd say the second way is better.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 will use a tiny amount more memory, but it will be a tiny bit faster due to one less dereferencing step.

There won't be much difference either way, unless you're computing over billions+ of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that matters **a lot** when it comes to performance, however I use the second option for better observation of the code, easier debugging and readibility like below:

```
float maxDepth = 0; 
int maxNumber = 0 

int defectNumber = defects.Total; 
for (int i = 0; i < defectNumber; i++) 
{ 
    float defectsCurrentDepth = defects[i].Depth;
    if (defectsCurrentDepth > maxDepth) 
    { 
        maxDepth = defectsCurrentDepth; 
        maxNumber = i; 
    } 
}
```